# Python; class is not defined

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have been self-teaching the IGCSE computer science(can already program) however I am having trouble with Array's.

My book uses this code as an example

```
import array

NoStudents = int(30)
Studentmarktest = array.array ('i',range(NoStudents+1))
for i in range(0,30):   
    Studentmarktest[Counter] = int(input("Enter students score"))
print (Studentmarktest)
```

However this example returns: `NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined`

Comment: I am _not_ impressed with a book / tutorial that tells you to do `NoStudents = int(30)`. My guess is that it's a Python adaptation of course material originally intended for another language.

Comment: Can anyone explain these upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code

```
for i in range(0,30):   
    Studentmarktest[Counter] = int(input("Enter students score"))
```

You used `i` as the index variable for the loop. But inside the loop you are using `Counter`. You simply have to change that:

```
for i in range(0,30):   
    Studentmarktest[i] = int(input("Enter students score"))
```

Comment: There is really no need to answer questions due to a simple typo/error like this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 We do a many things a day we don't really need to do. As long as they don't hurt anybody I have no problem with doling them.

Comment: But answering typo questions does hurt someone - several someones, in fact. The site as a whole becomes cluttered and more difficult to navigate when it's littered with useless questions and answers like these.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, and that is why there are tools and processes for that and they have been discussed extensively. So if *you* think the question should be closed: vote for closing.

Comment: You make it sound subjective. It isn't subjective. Typo questions and answers do not belong on this site.